# python - BadValueError: Expected date, got u'2018-04-25'

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to get the date from datepicker and store it in my model but it gives the following error

> **python - BadValueError: Expected date, got u'2018-04-25'**

Model:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb


class Bookings(ndb.Model):
    bookingName = ndb.StringProperty()
    bookingFrom = ndb.DateProperty()
```

Class Method:

```
bookingName = self.request.get('bookingName')
bookingFrom = self.request.get('bookingFrom')
user = users.get_current_user()
myuser_key = ndb.Key('MyUser', user.user_id())
myuser = myuser_key.get()
new_address = Bookings(bookingName=bookingName, bookingFrom=bookingFrom)
myuser.addresses.append(new_address)
myuser.put()
self.redirect('/')
```

Html:

```
 <form action="/" method="post">
          Line 1: <input type="text" name="bookingName"/><br/>
          Line 2: <input type="date" name="bookingFrom"/><br/>
          <input type="submit" name="button" value="Add Address"/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, you pass a string as `bookingFrom` but `Bookings` expects it to be a date object so you will need to convert it.

```
from datetime import datetime

...
new_address = Bookings(bookingName=bookingName, 
                       bookingFrom=datetime.strptime(bookingFrom, '%Y-%m-%d'))
...
```

Comment: Got it working! I wonder why they didn't put an example on cloud.